# Issues with Scipy interpolate griddata

Tags: python, scipy, grid, interpolation, netcdf

I have a [netcdf file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RKzv3sGRpqt5HXFTVRRMeSNv45_xmyIj/view?usp=sharing) with a spatial resolution of 0.05º and I want to regrid it to a spatial resolution of 0.01º like [this other netcdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lHmk4l5uqhRUK-fBmaSBQ7-mQDiT1bAj/view?usp=sharing). I tried using scipy.interpolate.griddata, but I am not really getting there, I think there is something that I am missing.

```
original_dataset = xr.open_dataset('to_regrid.nc')
target_dataset= xr.open_dataset('SSTA_L4_MED_0_1dg_2022-01-18.nc')
```

According to [scipy.interpolate.griddata documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html), I need to construct my interpolation pipeline as following:

> grid = griddata(points, values, (grid_x_new, grid_y_new),
> method='nearest')

So in my case, I assume it would be as following:

```
#Saving in variables the old and new grids
grid_x_new = target_dataset['lon']
grid_y_new = target_dataset['lat']
grid_x_old = original_dataset ['lon']
grid_y_old = original_dataset ['lat']

points = (grid_x_old,grid_y_old)
values = original_dataset['analysed_sst'] #My variable in the netcdf is the sea surface temp.
```

Now, when I run griddata:

```
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
grid = griddata(points, values, (grid_x_new, grid_y_new),method='nearest')
```

I am getting the following error:

> ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single
> shape

I assume it has something to do with the lat/lon array shapes. I am quite new to netcdf field and don't really know what can be the issue here. Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your original code the indices in grid_x_old and grid_y_old should correspond to each unique coordinate in the dataset. To get things working correctly something like the following will work:

```
import xarray as xr
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
original_dataset = xr.open_dataset('to_regrid.nc')
target_dataset= xr.open_dataset('SSTA_L4_MED_0_1dg_2022-01-18.nc')
#Saving in variables the old and new grids
grid_x_old = original_dataset.to_dataframe().reset_index().loc[:,["lat", "lon"]].lon
grid_y_old = original_dataset.to_dataframe().reset_index().loc[:,["lat", "lon"]].lat

grid_x_new = target_dataset.to_dataframe().reset_index().loc[:,["lat", "lon"]].lon
grid_y_new = target_dataset.to_dataframe().reset_index().loc[:,["lat", "lon"]].lat
values = original_dataset.to_dataframe().reset_index().loc[:,["lat", "lon", "analysed_sst"]].analysed_sst
points = (grid_x_old,grid_y_old)
grid = griddata(points, values, (grid_x_new, grid_y_new),method='nearest')
```

Comment: Nailed it. Thank you very much @Robert Wilson !!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using xesm for regridding xarray datasets. The code below will regrid your dataset:

```
import xarray as xr
import xesmf as xe
original_dataset = xr.open_dataset('to_regrid.nc')
target_dataset= xr.open_dataset('SSTA_L4_MED_0_1dg_2022-01-18.nc')
regridder = xe.Regridder(original_dataset, target_dataset, "bilinear")
dr_out = regridder(original_dataset)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The problem with xesmf is that, as they say, the ESMPy conda package is currently only available for Linux and Mac OSX, not for windows, which is I am using.